# render partial from events plugin php in October CMS

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I'm trying to update a partial on the front end after an event has been fired in October.  I get an error returned saying renderpartial method not found, but if I put the code anywhere else the event isn't registered and I get nothing.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
function boot(){
        Event::listen('ordready', function(){
             return [
                '#orderboard' => $this->renderPartial('orderboard')
            ];
        });
    }
```

Comment: dear, I think there is some misunderstanding event and render-partial do not work like that. to update partial on client side you must need to fire AJAX call to cms. and event is server side code it can not push partial to client. best option is to fire periodically fire AJAX to your component to check order is ready or not and based on that return render-partial.

Comment: Thanks Hardik, you've pointed me in the right direction.